# How to get tweets by hashtag?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I would like to get multiple tweets of some hashtag, for example "iPhone".

Use the following code, but this will result in an error that sends the URL in red.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                cache: false,
                url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=iPhone&count=100",
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);

                }, 

                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('We have a problem!');
                }
            });
```

Comment: That's an old URL - have a look here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Comment: I tried the following, but still get the same error: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=iPhone&count=100`. Also the example gives me a GET error: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%23freebandnames&since_id=24012619984051000&max_id=250126199840518145`

Answer (score 0):

Is your error
    {"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}

Please refer https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search:- *Please note that now API v1.1 requires that the request must be authenticated, check Authentication & Authorization documentation for more details on how to do it.*

Answer (score 0):

use titter4j library and following code

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
                                .setOAuthConsumerKey("your key")
                                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(
                                        "your key")
                                .setOAuthAccessToken(
                                        "your key")
                                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(
                                        "your key");
                        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
                        Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
                            Query query = new Query("#iphone7");
                            query.setCount(100);
                            try {
                                result = twitter.search(query);
                                tweets.addAll(result.getTweets());
                                System.out.println("Gathered " + tweets.size() + " tweets");
                        } catch (TwitterException te) {
                                System.out.println("Couldn't connect: " + te.toString());
                        }
```